# pyql is not accessable after its installation from native for Ubuntu14.04 python2.7

Tags: enthought

After installing pyql from [the package source](https://github.com/enthought/pyql)(according to its own wizard [described in this file](https://github.com/enthought/pyql/blob/master/docs/source/getting_started.rst)) on Ubuntu 14.04 into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ folder, all tests finished with success. This folder includes all additional installed packages, which are accessible, from the python using native import command.
But, this specific installation python don’t see, and I cannot import anything from it.
Have you any idea, what I need to define in addition?
Thanks,
Yigal B.

There are results of my sys.path:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

['/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']

python -c 'from quantlib.settings import __quantlib_version__; print __quantlib_version__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named quantlib.settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the content of you sys.path? And the output of

`python  -c 'from quantlib.settings import __quantlib_version__; print __quantlib_version__'`

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, I didn't see your comment previously. You can see the results of the commands above in my original question. Thanks.